# Dynamic query does not run on EXEC

Tags: sql, t-sql, dynamic

In the query below, when I use the print statement the full query prints out as expected and I can pick it up and execute no problems. But if instead of printing it, I run it with EXEC, I get an error which
says incorrect syntax by taking some portion of the query and saying that it's an incorrect identifier, as if the executor just sees a partial query and not the full thing. As you can see, I am using varchar(max), which ought to fit the entire query string. Anyone have any ideas here? Thanks!

```
declare @RollUp varchar = "hello"
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) 
SET @SQL =
'INSERT INTO #RESULT 
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,"[Member0].[MEMBER_CAPTION]") AS Zeroth,
CONVERT(VARCHAR,"[Member1].[MEMBER_CAPTION]") AS First,
CONVERT(VARCHAR,"[Member2].[MEMBER_CAPTION]") AS Second,
CONVERT(VARCHAR,"[Member3].[MEMBER_CAPTION]") AS Third,
CONVERT(VARCHAR,"[Member4].[MEMBER_CAPTION]") AS Fourth,
CONVERT(VARCHAR,"[Member5].[MEMBER_CAPTION]") AS Fifth,
CONVERT(VARCHAR,"[Member6].[MEMBER_CAPTION]") AS Sixth,
CONVERT(VARCHAR,"[Member7].[MEMBER_CAPTION]") AS Seventh,
CONVERT(MONEY,"[Measures].[MyMeasure]") AS Eighth
FROM OPENROWSET(''MSOLAP'',''DataSource=MyServer;Initial Catalog=Sales'' ,''    
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[MyMeasure]
AS (SUM (StrToMember("[Trans Date].[Year - Quarter - Month - Date].[Month].&["+ Format(Now(),"yyyyMM") + "]").lag(12)
:StrToMember("[Trans Date].[Year - Quarter - Month - Date].[Month].&["+ Format(Now(),"yyyyMM") + "]").lag(1)    
,[Measures].[Revenue])) 
SELECT NON EMPTY([Measures].[MyMeasure]) on 0,
NON EMPTY({[Commission Category Current].[EP Business Line].[Business Line].members *
[Sales].[Product].members *
[Territory].[Territories].[Territory].members *
[Purchasing Site].[Customers].[Customer].members *
[Purchasing Site].[Cust ID].Children *
[Site].[Customers].[Customer].members *
[Site].[Cust ID].Children} *
[Territory].[Countries].[Territory RollUp].&[''' + @RollUp + ''']
) on 1  FROM SALES
)'''


DECLARE @SQL1 VARCHAR(MAX)= Replace(Replace(@SQL, '[''', '['), ''']', ']')

print @sql1

EXEC @SQL1
```

Comment: Try syntax checking the result of the `print` statement.

Answer (score 1):

The table `#Result` is not known when you run `exec`.  It is defined in the outer scope but not inherited in the inner scope.  You cannot use temporary tables like this, unless they are global temporary tables (preceded by `##` instead of just `#`).

Also, you should never use `varchar()` in SQL Server without a length.  The default length depends on the context and might not be long enough.  In other words, you should have a length for `varchar()` in the `convert()` statements.

Comment: Thans for your reply, I will update the varchar, it was a lazy move on my part, however I do not think that is the problem. This is inside an SP, declaring a variable at the SP level makes it available to the Exec of the dynamic query, without the need for a global variable. Globals are dangerous because multiple sessions have access to them and they can be changed. In my case I need everything to be contained within the current running session of the sp.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by breaking up the query in 4 substrings, then at the end just do

EXEC (@STR1 + @STR2 + @STR3 + @STR4).

I'm not sure how a varchar(max) doesn't accept a dynamic string that is clearly not greater than 1000 characters long. Unless the editor is adding hidden chars.

In any event, fixed.